# How are relative URIs resolved in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, relative-path

#### Introduction

I recently struggled on how relative `Uri`s are being resolved, because it was other than I expected it to be.

**Note:** I know that I can fix this issue by using the *package syntax* with `UriKind.Absolute` to solve my issue. I am really interested in **How are relative `Uri`s resolved in WPF?**

*So, lets continue with my ...*

#### Example

In my Project, I have got the following folder-hierarchy:

- Project Root/

  - images/  *(these images are `Copy [...]: Do Not Copy` `Build Action: Resource`)*

    - `someimage.png`
  - utility/

    - ActionColumn/

      - `MyActionColumn.cs` *this is a lookless control*
  - view/

    - `MyUsercontrol.cs`

In `MyActionColumn` I programmatically create a `ContextMenu` relatively linking to `someimage.png`.

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
{
    Icon = new Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative))
    },
    Header = "...", Command = MyCommand, CommandParameter = param
});
```

In `MyUsercontrol` I use `MyActionColumn`. This works. The `ContextMenu` is displaying `someimage.png`.

*But...*

Upon refactoring `view/MyUsercontrol.cs` to `view/somefolder/anotherfolder/MyUsercontrol.cs`, the `Uri` won't work nomore. This indicates, that the `Uri` is resolved using `MyUsercontrol` as basepath, because `new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../../images/someimage.png"` will fix this issue.

#### Questions:

Can someone explain, why it's not the location of `MyActionColumn` which is used to resolve this relative path?

How is the base path determined, especially when using images compiled into the assembly (`Build Action: Resource`)?

Comment: It makes no sense to load an assembly resource from any other URI then a Resource File Pack URI. And you don't have to set `UriKind.Absolute` when you use it. So simply write `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/someimage.png")`.

Comment: @Clemens yes you are right. Anyway WPF seems to have problems with relative paths very often. All I wanted to know, is how they work.

Comment: Then use content files instead of assembly resources. I.e. actual files on your disk.